# Keras error about array shape but shape seems correct

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, keras, nlp

I'm trying to train a simple model with Keras and python. The text is preprocessed perfectly. But when I try to fit it I get the following error:

```
File "main.py", line 47, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=3)
  File "/home/shamildacoder/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 952, in fit
    batch_size=batch_size)
  File "/home/shamildacoder/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 789, in _standardize_user_data
    exception_prefix='target')
  File "/home/shamildacoder/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/training_utils.py", line 138, in standardize_input_data
    str(data_shape))
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_2 to have shape (121885,) but got array with shape (1000,)
```

But `print(x_train.shape)` and `print(y_train.shape)` both return `(121885, 1000)`. I don't see any reason.

Code: https://pastebin.com/afnzBf6B

```
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential

data = open('movie_lines.txt', encoding='ISO-8859-1')
lines = [line for line in data]
filtered_lines = []

for line in lines:
    sentence = line.split('+++$+++')[4].strip(' ')
    filtered_lines.append(sentence)

train_size = int(len(filtered_lines) * .8)
train_portion = filtered_lines[:train_size]
test_portion = filtered_lines[train_size:]

x_lines = train_portion[::2]
y_lines = train_portion[1::2]
x_test = test_portion[::2]
y_test = test_portion[1::2]
vocab_size = 1000
print('Prepared data')

def prepare_text(text):
    tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=vocab_size)
    tokenizer.fit_on_texts(text)
    matrix = tokenizer.texts_to_matrix(text)
    return matrix


x_train = prepare_text(x_lines)
print('matrixed x')
y_train = prepare_text(y_lines)
print('matrixed y')
print(f'X shape: {x_train.shape}')
print(f'Y shape: {y_train.shape}')

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(vocab_size,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(len(y_lines), activation='softmax'))

model.compile(
        loss='categorical_crossentropy',
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy',]
        )
print('Created and compiled model')

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=32, epochs=3)
print('Test Score:'+score[0])
print('Test Accuracy:'+score[1])
```

Comment: Shouldn't your y_train be just a single column of values with len `121885`?

Comment: the thing is, I'm trying to input some text data as a matrix and get some text data back. So, what should i put the labels/y_train as?

Comment: Ok I have no experience with such analysis. I was thinking in terms of a single output variable. May be someone with keras expertise will join soon.

Comment: let's see then.

Comment: Could you post a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: don't know how I'm supposed to do that. I gave the code and the error. and a few lines of the data would probably be worthless

Answer (score 1):

In the preprocessing stage you are using [`texts_to_matrix()`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/2c7ef1d27bff4a24fe8bd2dc3800ccdebfc08a75/keras_preprocessing/text.py#L369) method which (with default arguments) returns the given sequences as rows of a matrix in one-hot encoded format. Now if you would like to use just Dense layers to go from a one-hot encoded sequence to another one-hot encoded sequence, you need to set the number of units in the last layer to the vocabulary size (i.e. number of columns in the matrix) and use `sigmoid` as the activation function of last layer:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(512, input_shape=(vocab_size,), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='sigmoid'))
```